# Cat VS vim/nano etc

Tags: vim, cat

When I open files in nano/vim I see characters which are not-visible using cat command in terminal.
I want to proceed only with output of cat command. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try `cat -v` which shows nonprinting characters.